# how to remove NullExceptionError from Session Variable

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008

I have a varible sem,which takes inputfrom the textbox but if the textbox is kept empty i want it to return "Please Enter a Semester"

```
    int sem;
    int parsevalue;
    if (int.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out parsevalue))
    {
        sem = parsevalue;
        Session["Sem"] = sem;
    }
    else
    {
        Literal2.Text = "Please Enter a Semester";
    }
```

But If the Textbox is empty the `Session["Sem"]` returns `NullExceptionError` in the `.aspx` file where i have used it.

I searched for the proper conversion using tryparse but could not understand it clearly as to how to print the above mentioned error message.
please help
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're assigning the Session variable only when there is a correct value, but you're always trying to access it. This will fail if the value is incorrect (and the Session variable is not set).

Here's your corrected code:

```
int sem;
int parsevalue;
if (int.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out parsevalue))
{
    sem = parsevalue;
}
else
{
    Literal2.Text = "Please Enter a Semester";
}
//Always set the Session variable when it's used somewhere else
Session["Sem"] = sem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["Sem"] = sem;
```

Actually:

```
 Session.Add("Sem", sem);
```

and

```
 Session["Sem"] = sem;
```

is a same

Comment: Actually, it's all the same, so it won't solve his problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Q1 Hi , I have a varible sem,which takes inputfrom the textbox but if the textbox is kept empty i want it to return "Please Enter a Semester"

```
    int sem;
    int parsevalue;

    var txt = TextBox2.Text

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && int.TryParse(text, out parsevalue))
    {
        sem = parsevalue;            
    }
    else
    {
        Literal2.Text = "Please Enter a Semester";
    }

    Session["Sem"] = sem;
```